# Double integral over modified Bessel function of the second kind of zeroth order

Tags: integration, special-functions, multiple-integral, bessel-functions

I am working on a project we I arrive at the integral
\begin{align}
\int_0^a \int_0^a K_0(|x-y|) \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \,,
\end{align}
where $K_0(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of zeroth order. I wonder if this integral can be evaluated analytically to arrive at an expression depending on the upper bound $a$, or if it is only possible to evaluate this integral numerically for a given value of $a$. I found an analytical expression for $a \rightarrow \infty$ on https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43, which is
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}K_{\nu}\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t=\tfrac{1}{2}\pi\sec\left(%
\tfrac{1}{2}\pi\nu\right),
\end{align}
but this is only a single integral and in my case the upper bound should not be infinity. I was not able to come up with an answer to this, my guess would be that it is only possible to evaluate it numerically. But maybe someone else knows more about this, all ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: The inner integral can be done analytically in terms of modified Struve functions. I don't know enough about them to know whether the outer integral can then be done analytically as well.

Comment: That said I'm a bit surprised that you end up with that because that involves $K_0$ at negative real values of its argument. Are you sure it's not $|x-y|$?

Comment: Yes, I guess $|x-y|$ should be the right argument, since the arguments of $K_0$ should be greater than 0. I will edit this to make it clear. Were can I find more about these Struve funtions? I took a quick look at https://dlmf.nist.gov/11 and could not find any relation to $K_0$.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43 but as I said this only solves the inner part of your problem. After that I don't actually know how to integrate the other stuff.

Comment: Ah yes, now I see it. Maybe I could use the series expansion of this modified Struve function and change the order of the integral and summation. Although this function does not seem to converge properly in order to use that and I would also have products of this series with other bessel functions. All together this would be a total mess, so I guess the best way to evaluate this would be numerically. Nonetheless, many thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, the integral expresses in terms of modified Struve functions. Using $$\int_0^a\!\!\!\int_0^a f(|x-y|)\,dx\,dy=2\int_0^a(a-z)f(z)\,dz$$ (consider the double integral as iterated, substitute $x=y+z$ and exchange the integrations, keeping track of the possible values of $y$ with $z\in(-a,a)$ fixed) and [these formulae](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43#i), one gets $$\int_0^a\!\!\!\int_0^a K_0(|x-y|)\,dx\,dy=\pi a^2\big(K_0(a)\mathbf{L}_{-1}(a)+K_1(a)\mathbf{L}_0(a)\big)-2\big(1-aK_1(a)\big).$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This seems like a nice and somewhat compact solution for this integral.